Titled question with text on same line
I'm using the exam class to type up my homework and the problems are picked out of a book, so I want to match the question numbers with the problem numbers from the book. Some questions are also written out without a question number. As a MWE, I have
\documentclass[answers]{exam}
\qformat{\textbf{\thequestiontitle}.\hfill}
\renewcommand{\solutiontitle}{\noindent Answer: \noindent}
\SolutionEmphasis{}
\unframedsolutions

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
    \titledquestion{2.2.4} Lorem Ipsum
    \begin{parts}
        \part Foo
        \begin{solution}
            Trivial.
        \end{solution}

        \part Bar
        \begin{solution}
            This is the solution.
        \end{solution}
    \end{parts}

    \titledquestion{Monte Carlo Exercise} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla condimentum sodales ipsum id luctus. Donec condimentum egestas posuere.
    \begin{solution}
        This is the solution
    \end{solution}
\end{questions}
\end{document}

which gives

But I want the text to be on the same line like this:

I was looking through the documentation and couldn't figure out how to do this. Also, I do want the parts to be indented. I found a partial solution which was to use \renewcommand\questionlabel{\thesection.\thequestion.} but this would require setting the section and question counter to be correct repeatedly and also doesn't account for question titles with text.
Edit: I found a solution that works for me. I did \qformat{\hfill} and then instead of \titledquestion{questiontitle} I did \question \textbf{questiontitle.}
It might add a little more space between questions, but I was actually kind of wanting to do that anyway. It's not the most elegant solution but it works for me. Not sure how it's received to accept your own answer to questions so I've just put it here as an edit for anyone who needs it.

Welcome to TeX.SE!

Thanks! @Mensch
